# How to make it possible to assign value to an array, while making it Impossible to assign each of the array elements individually?

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine, properties, indexer

I m working on a Unity3D project and using the `Mesh` class,
inside the `Mesh` class there is a member variable `Vector3[] vertices`.
Now, while setting `mesh.vertices` in the following way is possible

```
Vector3[] v = new Vector3[3];
v[0] = new Vector3[0,0,0];
v[1] = new Vector3[1,1,1];
v[2] = new Vector3[2,2,2];
mesh.vertices = v;
```

setting an individual element, like this: `mesh.vertices[0] = new Vector3(1,1,1)` seems to have no effect.
(also,  `mesh.vertices[0].x = 5` have no effect as well).
When i say no effect i mean that the code does compile and run with no errors, but the elements of the array are not changing.
Since the vertices represent a surface, It seems logical that the designer wanted for all them to be changed together.

I have tried to mimic this magical functionality with a simple code to no avail.
What am i missing?
Is it something with Properties?
Indexers?
Some weird combination?

```
class Student
{
  private int[] grades = {92, 99, 96};
  public int[] Grades{
      get{
          Console.WriteLine("getter: ");
          return grades;
      }
      set{
          Console.WriteLine("setter: ");
          grades = value;
      }
  }
}

class HelloWorld
{
  static void Main ()
  {
    int[] low_grades = {53, 51, 55};
    Student student = new Student();
    student.Grades = low_grades; // This assignment is possible and this is O.K.
    student.Grades[0] = 52;  // This assignment is Possible and this is NOT O.K.
  }
}
```

How can i make it possible for the client to assign an array to my member variable, but to stop him from assigning values to individual elements in the array?

Comment: You can broaden your audience for your question if, for those of us who do not want to go to the trouble of installing the Unity3d environment, you would provide more detail about the Unity3d scenario you're trying to emulate. Specifically: when you say it's "impossible", what does that mean _exactly_? Do you get an error? Run-time? Compile-time? Does updating the vertex value just not have any effect? What are the Unity3d declarations for the `Mesh` class and its `vertices` member? Is that a field? A property?

Comment: Based on the source code [here](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/UnityCsReference/blob/master/Runtime/Export/Mesh.cs).  It looks like it might be creating a new array each time you acces `vertices`, which means updating that array will not actually update anything inside of the `Mesh` object.  So if you did `public int[] Grades { get { var r = new int[grades.Length]; grades.CopyTo(r, 0); return r;} set { grades = value; } }` that might get you the behavior you want.

Comment: Brilliant. thank you!

Comment: why was i downvoted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don’t want direct access to set elements, make it a private field and provide a method to set the array.  If you want you can also provide a method to return a copy of the array as a separate reference.